# Cookies in Network Tab of chrome developer tool

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, developer-tools

How can i get cookies from chrome network tab (developer tool), one of our third party is telling us to get cookies from network tab, as they are storing cookies at newtwork tab.

And i want to get that cookies in php ?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are placed in `Resources` tab in `Cookies` in the tree on the left.

In PHP you can get cookies via [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) superglobal variable